# Meteor Javascript Prototype

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there a way to add my own 'prototype functions' in meteor?

For i.e.,

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + this.className + ' ');
};
```

Is there a way I can use this in the client side folder and use it everywhere in the client folder?

Comment: So are you asking about creating prototypes or about variable scoping? Or both?

Comment: If you put it in client/lib, it should be accessible everywhere else.

Comment: @Kyll Prototypes for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor is a Node.JS framework which is purely JavaScript. From that you can do everything you could normally do, including adding methods to existing prototypes or modifying them altogether (like changing the `Array` prototype to add methods on arrays).

However, this behaviour is discouraged. It creates very high coupling between your code and the ways you defined the environment. It may also cause strong incompatibilities and dysfunctions in libraries.

If you need to change a prototype (for example to add your own features) on a package/plugin/framework, please refer to its documentation (some may advise to rather compose objects with an `extend()` for example).

Do not change the default JS objects prototypes.

Here's a small example on how to create a custom prototype and then use it with an object:

```
var userPrototype, user;

userPrototype = {
  sayHi : function() {
    if(_.has(this, name)) {
      return 'Hi, my name is ' + this.name + '!';
    }
    return '... Who am I?';
  }
};

user = Object.create(userPrototype); //user has userPrototype as prototype

user.name = 'Will';
user.sayHi(); //Returns 'Hi, my name is Will!'
```

As a bonus, here's a [free book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) about JS and prototypes.

Comment: Thank you. I started web-development when meteor 1.0 . I wanted to try creating my own prototypes to practice JS.

Comment: It goes out of the scope of the question, but in that case there's only one thing I can recommend about JS: Read, practice, read more, practice more. Don't forget to read as many blogs and books as possible (the link I provided is an awesome start), JS is one of the most misunderstood language.

Comment: But what about when I want to make a "custom"/my own prototype?

Comment: Added an example. Read some books and blogs for more about prototypes =)

Comment: This is more than enough. Thank you so much! You are always a great teacher :)